# Python Sqllite3 : Inserting many lists with different lengths at once

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, database-design, list-manipulation

can you please advise me how to insert many of lists in python? I tried the below code but the problem is that when I insert the data, it is inserted in one field of the table for every list I have.

The second issue is: every list has different length because when i tried to insert all of lists together in one SQL execute, OUTPUT was 
`List index out of range`

Please help me with the right code formula.

Here are the test lists:

```
ListLinks = ["Link 1", "Link 2", "Link 3", "Link 4", "Link 5", "Link 6", "Link 7", "Link 8", 
"Link 9", "Link 10"]

ListNames = ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5", "Name 6", "Name 7", "Name 8", 
"Name 9", "Name 10"]

ListAddress = ["Add 1", "Add 2", "Add 3", "Add 4", "Add 5", "Add 6", "Add 7", "Add 8", "Add 9", 
"Add 10"]

ListPhone = ["Phone 1", "Phone 2", "Phone 3", "Phone 4", "Phone 5", "Phone 6", "Phone 7", "Phone 
8", "Phone 9", "Phone 10"]

ListCategory = ["Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3", "Cat 4", "Cat 5", "Cat 6", "Cat 7", "Cat 8", "Cat 9", 
"Cat 10"]

ListDirection = ["Dir 1", "Dir 2", "Dir 3", "Dir 4", "Dir 5", "Dir 6", "Dir 7", "Dir 8", "Dir 
9", "Dir 10"]
```

And here is the sample of my code:

```
import sqlite3
def InsertDB(listOne, listTwo, listThree, listFour, listFive, listSix):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("SQLTestDB.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""create table if not exists YellowCompanies(CompanyLink text,CompanyName text,CompanyAddress text,CompanyPhone text,CompanyCategory text,CompanyDirection text)""")
    connection.commit()
    for Index1 in range(len(listOne)):
        DataOne = listOne[Index1]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO YellowCompanies (CompanyLink) VALUES (?)", ((DataOne,)))
        connection.commit()
    for Index2 in range(len(listTwo)):
        DataTwo = listTwo[Index2]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO YellowCompanies (CompanyAddress) VALUES (?)", ((DataTwo,)))
        connection.commit()

    for Index3 in range(len(listThree)):
        DataThree = listThree[Index3]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO YellowCompanies (CompanyCategory) VALUES (?)", ((DataThree,)))
        connection.commit()

    for Index4 in range(len(listFour)):
        DataFour = listFour[Index4]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO YellowCompanies (CompanyDirection) VALUES (?)", ((DataFour,)))
        connection.commit()

    for Index5 in range(len(listFive)):
        DataFive = listFive[Index5]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO YellowCompanies (CompanyName) VALUES (?)", ((DataFive,)))
        connection.commit()

    for Index6 in range(len(listSix)):
        DataSix = listSix[Index6]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO YellowCompanies (CompanyPhone) VALUES (?)", ((DataSix,)))
        connection.commit()

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, comment if you need explain

```
import sqlite3
def InsertDB(listOne, listTwo, listThree, listFour, listFive, listSix):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("SQLTestDB.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""create table if not exists YellowCompanies(CompanyLink text,CompanyName text,CompanyAddress text,CompanyPhone text,CompanyCategory text,CompanyDirection text)""")
    connection.commit()

    # Zip to list of tuples
    values = zip(listOne, listTwo, listThree, listFour, listFive, listSix)
    # Building values for sql
    sql = "INSERT INTO YellowCompanies VALUES {}".format(', '.join(map(str, values)))
    cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

If the list is from user input then this is not a version that prevent sql injection, also if the list have one or zero elements this might cause error

Comment: i will try, and tell u the resulti, fat thanks for paying attention